# Insert values from one data frame into another based on values of one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df1, in `R` that has two columns `BANK-CODE` and `BANK-NAME`.

```
       BANK-CODE       BANK-NAME
1      B001            Bank of America
2      B002            Bank of China
3      B003            Barclays
4      B004            BNP Paribas
5      B005            Citibank
```

A second dataframe, df2, also contains these columns along with a few others

```
             DATE       TIME-ZONE  BANK-NAME    BANK-CODE
1 2019-01-01T11:10:20+00:00 NA     Mizuho       NA
2 2019-01-04T17:51:11+00:00 NA     Sberbank     NA
3 2019-01-05T02:46:11+00:00 NA     Lloyds       NA
4 2019-01-05T06:13:46+00:00 NA     Barclays     NA
5 2019-01-05T07:52:16+00:00 NA     Emirates NBD NA
```

My goal is to replace the NA values for `BANK-CODE` in df2, with those in df1, corresponding to the name of the bank, so `df2[4,4]` should be `B003`. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` :

```
df2$BANK_CODE <- df1$BANK_CODE[match(df2$BANK_NAME, df1$BANK_NAME)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library("imputeTS")
df2 <- na.replace(BANK-CODE)//or sth like this
```

you can use something like this?! you just need to install the package(imputeTS) first.
Does that help?